# What is the difference between encode/decode in Python 2/3

Tags: python, string, encoding

In Python 3, we use `"string".encode()` and `"string".decode()` to convert an Unicode string to a bytes string, or convert a bytes string to an Unicode string.

In Python 2, we have `str()` and `unicode()`, we can `encode()` and `decode()` to them, too. But, is there any difference between Python 3?

Comment: Python 3.x has full UTF8 support. It would mean that Python 2.x might make errornous conversions or will have problems converting UTF8 (specialty using `str()`). I have experience with Katakana being horrible to work with in Python 2.7. I always used binary/hex conversion to fix codecrashes on decoding problems.

Comment: Sounds terrible. I'm working on a network program with CJK characters. So, I should keep an eye when: 1. User's input, 2. String's operating 3. Send to the web server. I want to porting a Python 2 SDK to Python 3, but I found I can not understand `encode()` and `decode()` with `str()` and `unicode()`, so I asked that question……

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python2, str is byte strings, unicode is unicode string. But some silly thing for encode and decode, details refer to http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Comment: That doesn't actually answer OP's question.

Comment: That's not true. In Python 2, `"a".encode().encode()` is possible, but it is illegal in Python 3. So, `str` is not fully as same as `bytes`.

Comment: @比尔盖子 You are correct, details you can refer to http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html